# NSLog symbol print on console?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

How to print symbol "%" in NSLog ???

```
NSLog(@"str %");
```

[image]

It gives warning

> incomplete format specifier

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try this NSLog(@"str %%")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
NSLog(@"str : %%");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just use two percent signs:

```
NSLog(@"str %%"); //prints "str %"
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW2) is the list of format specifiers for all types of data printing which can be useful for iOS programming.

Answer (score 1):

You need to print like this

```
NSLog(@"%%");
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
NSLog(@"str  %%");
```